# how do i track downloads for files in my google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I need a way of tracking downloads by users of my site,  for mp3  files in my cloud storage? Aside from storage logs, are there any other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

There's a storage logging feature: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty old, but I thought I would share my solution in case anyone is looking for a solution still. You need to enable access logs and then write some scriptage to download and parse the access logs.

I used Ruby and here's the meat of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'fileutils'

temp_dir = "/tmp/access-logs"
output_file = "/tmp/download-count.csv"

# Clean up the existing access logs
FileUtils.rm_rf(temp_dir)
FileUtils.mkdir(temp_dir)
`/usr/bin/gsutil -m cp "gs://my_access_logs/FusionAuthAccesssLog_usage_*" #{temp_dir} > /dev/null 2>&1`

# Collect the counts
counts = Hash.new(0)
Dir.foreach(temp_dir) do |file|
  if File.file?("#{temp_dir}/#{file}")
    date = file.gsub(/MyAccesssLog_usage_([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2}).*/, '\1\2\3')
    File.readlines("#{temp_dir}/#{file}").each do |l|
      if l =~ /my-file.zip"/
        counts[date] = counts[date] + 1
      end
    end
  end
end

File.open(output_file, "w", :encoding => "UTF-8") do |f|
  # Write the header
  f.puts("Date,Download count\n")

  # Write the counts
  counts.sort.each do |date,count|
    f.puts("#{date},#{count}\n")
  end
end
```

I wrote a blog post on this that goes over the script in detail as well. Here's the link: https://fusionauth.io/blog/2018/09/20/download-counts-from-google-cloud-storage